# How would i iterate through a list of lists and perform computational filtering?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

this one is a bit of a doozy.

At a high level, I'm trying to figure out how to run a nested for loop. I'm essentially trying to iterate through columns and rows, and perform a computational check to make sure outcomes match a specified requirement - if so, they loop to the next row, if not, they are kicked out and the loop moves onto the next user.

Specifically, I want to perform a T-Test between a control/treatment group of users, and make sure the result is less than a pre-determined value.

### Example:

I have my table of values - **"DF"** - there are 7 columns. The user_id column specifies the user's unique identifier. The user_type column is a binary classifier, users can be of either T (treatment) or C (control) types. The 3 "hour" columns are dummy number columns, values that I'll perform computation on. The mon column is the month, and tval is the number that the computation will have to be less than to be accepted.

In this case, the month is all January data. Each month can have a different tval.

#### DF

```
| user_id | user_type | hour1 | hour2 | hour3 | mon | tval |
|---------|-----------|-------|-------|-------|-----|------|
| 4       | T         |   1   |   10  |  100  |  1  | 2.08 |
| 5       | C         |   2   |   20  |  200  |  1  | 2.08 |
| 6       | C         |   3   |   30  |  300  |  1  | 2.08 |
| 7       | T         |   4   |   40  |  400  |  1  | 2.08 |
| 8       | T         |   5   |   50  |  500  |  1  | 2.08 |
```

My goal is to iterate through each T user - and for each, loop through each C user. For each "Pair", I want to perform computation (t-test) between their hour 1 values. If the value is less than the tval, move to hour2 values, etc. If not, it gets kicked out and the loop moves to the next C user without completing that C user's loop. If it passes all value checks, the user_ids of each would be appended to a list or something external.

The output would hopefully look like a table of pairs. The T user and C user that have successfully iterated through all hour columns, and the month that passed (as each set of users have data for all 12 months).

#### Output:

```
| t_userid |  c_userid | month | 
|--------- |-----------|-------|
| 4        | 5         |   1   | 
| 8        | 6         |   1   |
```

To sum it all up:

```
For each T user:
    For each C user:
        If t-test on t.hour1 and c.hour1 is less than X number (passing test):
            move to next hour (hour2) and repeat
        If all hours pass, add pair (T user_id, c_user_id) to separate list/series/df,etc
        else: skip following hours and move to next C user.
```

I'm wondering if my data format is also incorrect. Would this be easier if I unpivoted my hourly data and iterated over each row? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks, and let me know if any clarification is necessary.

#### EDIT:

So far I've split the data between Treat and Control groups, and calculated average and standard deviation for a users monthly data (which is normally broken down by day) and added them as columns, hour1_avg and hour1_stdev. I've attempted another for loop, but am getting a ValueError.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know this is due to the fact that I cant compare a pandas Series to a float, int, str, etc. I will make another post addressing this question.

Here's what I have so far:

```py
for i in treatment.user_id:
    for i in control.user_id:
        if np.absolute((treatment['hour1_avg'] - control['hour1_avg'])/np.sqrt((treatment['hour1_stdev']**2/31)+(control['hour1_stdev']**2/31))) > treatment.tval:
            "End loop, move to next control user"
        else:
            "copy paste if statement above, but for hour2, etc etc"
```

Comment: I don't understand your grouping.  How can `T8` and `C6` go together, when in `hour2`, `50 - 30` is clearly not less than `2`.  It doesn't seem as though `hour3` would work either.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't consider that. Those are just dummy numbers. For the sake of example, let's just say they "pass". My actual data would be much closer to the tval, I just didn't want to try and reverse engineer answers for the example. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split the dataframe into control and treatment groups
2. Make join of the resulting dataframes on a constant field (will create all pairs)
3. Use a combination of `apply` and `any` to make the decision
4. Filter out the join using the decision vector

Code to illustrate the idea:

```
# assuming the input is in df
control = df[df['user_type'] == 'C']
treatment = df[df['user_type'] == 'T']

# part 2: pairs will be created month-wise. 
# If you want all vs all, create a temp field, e.g.: control['_temp'] = 1
pairs = treatment.merge(control, left_on='mon', right_on='mon')

# part 3
def test(row):
    # all will stop executing at the first False
    return all(
        row['hours_%d_x' % i] - row['hours_%d_y' % i] < row['t_val'] 
        for i in range())
# all_less is a series of bool
all_less = pairs.apply(test, axis=1)

# part 4
output = pairs.loc[all_less, ['user_id_x', 'user_id_y', 'mon']].rename(
    columns={'user_id_x': 't_user_id', 'user_id_y': 'c_user_id'})
```

Comment: Logically this makes great sense, and would work perfectly, but I am currently running into memory errors. In reality, I have over 150,000 control users and 2000 treatment users. I was thinking something like a looping through the pairs, and kicking out those that don't match to circumvent the memory restraints. That way I don't have to commit everything to memory all at once. I'm going to attempt another nested loop to see if I can create only matching pairs without having to use extra space.

Comment: Forgot to mention there are over 100 columns as well. And this is only one month out of 5 years! Quite a bit of data haha.

Comment: Yes, looping makes sense in this context. Can you confirm that only the same month records should be matched?

Comment: Correct. Each user will have data in all 12 months, but I am looking to match month to month. So a treatment user who matches a control user in january can match someone else entirely in february, etc. I'll update my original question with another for loop i attempted.